# Backbone model not instantiating in collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a backbone model like so

```
define([
'underscore',
'backbone'
],function( _,Backbone) {
    var Task =  Backbone.Model.extend({
        //api url
        url:'',

        methodToURL: {
        'read': './api/tasks/index',
        'create': './api/tasks/task',
        'update': './api/tasks/task',
        'delete': './api/tasks/task'
        },
        sync: function(method, model, options) {
            options = options || {};
            options.url = this.methodToURL[method.toLowerCase()];

            Backbone.sync(method, model, options);
        }
    });
    return Task;
});
```

And a collection

```
define(['underscore','backbone','models/task'],function( _,Backbone,Task) {
    var TaskCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        //Model
        model:Task,
        //api url
        url:'',

        methodToURL: {
        'read': './api/tasks/index',
        'create': './api/tasks/task',
        'update': './api/tasks/task',
        'delete': './api/tasks/task'
        },

        sync: function(method, model, options) {
            options = options || {};
            options.url = this.methodToURL[method.toLowerCase()];

            Backbone.sync(method, model, options);
        },
        //construct
        initialize: function() {
            this.sort_key = 'end';
            this._model = new Task();
            this.fetch();
        },

        comparator: function(a,b) {
            a = a.get(this.sort_key);
            b = b.get(this.sort_key);
            return a > b ?  1
                 : a < b ? -1
                 :          0;
        },

        mark_complete: function(task_id) {
            var task_status = 0;
                    console.log(this.model);
            this.model.save({id:task_id,task_status:task_status});
        },

        mark_incomplete: function(task_id) {
            var task_status = 1;
                    console.log(this.model);
            this.model.save({id:task_id,task_status:task_status});
        },

        sort_by_status: function() {
            this.sort_key = 'task_status';
            this.sort();
        },

        sort_by_task_tag: function() {
            this.sort_key = 'task_group';
            this.sort();
        }
    });
    return TaskCollection;
});
```

When i the mark_complete method runs the model is logged to the console, but it logs this
"`function (){ parent.apply(this, arguments); }` " and says "`function (){ parent.apply(this, arguments); } has no method 'save'`";
Am guessing the model is supposed to be instantiated so the collection can have access it to its methods, so what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `model` property is just a constructor that `Collection` uses when you add a model to the collection. It is intended to make your life easier when you try to input data to the collection. Instead of always calling the constructor when adding a `Task` model to `TaskCollection`, you'd just input a JavaScript object and it will do the same thing.

So this is how your code would look like when you would want to insert a model *without* setting the `model` property to your `TaskCollection`

```
taskCollection.add(new Task({ 
    name: "Get Milk",
    description: "We're out of milk. There's a sale going on at the local supermarket." 
}));

// If you wanted to just input just the JSON object without calling the
// constructor, then you can't.
```

And this is how your code would look like if you *had* set the `model` property

```
taskCollection.add({
    name: "Get Milk",
    description: "We're out of milk. There's a sale going on at the local supermarket." 
});
```

As you can see, you don't need to call the `Task` constructor; the instance of `TaskCollection` will call it for you.

And this is why instances of `TaskCollection` will only have the `model` property set to the actual constructor of `Task`, not an initialized version.